# Flask Heroku Correct Procfile

Tags: python, heroku, flask, flask-wtforms, procfile

I'm trying to use Heroku to push my Flask app to the web. I think I have everything down, except the Procfile. Here is what my file directory looks like:
[image]

My main.py is:

```py
from application import app
```

My **init**.py is:

```py
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

db = MongoEngine()
db.init_app(app)
from application import routes
```

What is the correct Procfile command here?
Thanks

Comment: What specific issues do you have? Have you seen this? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python

Comment: just add `web: gunicorn main:app` in Procfile